# How to perform mann kendall trend test on multiple levels

Tags: r, group-by, summarize

I am working with station precipitation data. Each station has precipitation data for 60 years and there are 30 stations. I want to perform a Mann Kendall trend test on each station to see if there is a significant trend for precipitation.

I've tried `group_by` with `summarise` to calculate Mann Kendall for each station over the course of 60 years.

Here's a small example where ID is the station and prcp is precipitation.

```
ID<-c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
prcp<-c(2,0,1,4,5,0,2,3,5,6)
df<-cbind(ID,prcp)

mk<-df %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(prcpmk=MannKendall(prcp))
```

Every time I do this I get the following error: `Column prcpmk must be length 1 (a summary value), not 5`

Part of the problem is the the MannKendall function returns 5 values. How can I specify just the p-value when trying to use `group_by`?

What I want is a df that just has the p-value:

```
  ID prcpmk
[1,]  1   0.20
[2,]  2   0.03
```

Comment: Maybe `MannKendall(prcp)$p.value`. From which library you get `MannKendall`

Comment: Yes! Thank you, that works. The answer is below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @A.Suliman, you're right.

This seems to work:

```
ID<-c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
prcp<-c(2,0,1,4,5,0,2,3,5,6)
df<-cbind(ID,prcp)

mk<-df %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(prcpmk=MannKendall(prcp)$sl)
```

Adding the `$sl` after MannKendall() specifies the p value. Alternatively, you could specify tau, Kendall Score (S), denominator (D) of variance of S (varS)